# Exclude certain pages from executing AdSense code

Tags: javascript, adsense

AdSense is limiting my account due to ad being displayed on page with no value to advertisers (login page). I am trying to exclude the AdSense code that is placed in index.php so that it does not execute on that page but I am getting Uncought SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input in console

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (window.location.pathname !== '/index.php/pl/edytuj-profil?view=login') {
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
                google_ad_client: "ca-pub-4673232933311358",
                enable_page_level_ads: true
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Original code that I rewrote is this:

```
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-4673232933311358",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
</script>
```

Thanks of any tips.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f57rd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't close the first line properly. It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.pathname !== '/index.php/pl/edytuj-profil?view=login') {
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
            google_ad_client: "ca-pub-4673232933311358",
            enable_page_level_ads: true
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using this in PHP, you could just leverage PHP to do the page checking for you and omit the AdSense code altogether on those pages. How to do it depends on the environment you are using. A very basic example:

```
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

if (strpos($actual_link, 'view=login') !== false) {
    echo "<script>
          (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
          google_ad_client: 'ca-pub-4673232933311358',
          enable_page_level_ads: true
          });
          </script>";
}
```

Comment: Yeah after posting my question I figured the same with the following code:

 <?php 
  $pageToExclude = "/index.php/pl/edytuj-profil?view=login";
  if ($pageToExclude != $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
   include "adsense.php";
  }
 ?> 

There is separate adsense.php file now that contains echoed AdSense code.

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: The solution is good but it does not answer the actual question. Kevin answered it.